# Factory not registered error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm having a problem with Factory Girl gem:

With the lines in my spec_helper.rb code:

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

I have the error:

```
ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: products
```

Ps: the file `spec/factories/products.rb` already exists

If I comment these lines, the error changes to:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `create_list'
```

The method create_list I used in my file `products_controller_spec.rb`:

```
describe "GET #index" do
  let(:my_products){ create_list(:products, 10) }
```

spec/factories/products.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :product do 
    name "MyString" 
    description "MyString" 
    price "10.5" 
    maker "MyString" 
   end 
end
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show the contents of `spec/factories/products.rb`, too.

Comment: FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
    name "MyString"
    description "MyString"
    price "10.5"
    maker "MyString"
  end
end

Comment: @CristiAllan please post the code into question body not in comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The factory name is `product`. Try:

`let(:my_products) { create_list(:product, 10) }`